# Redirect to same page after login becuse of session time out in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi is there a anyway to land same page after sign in because of session time out in asp.net web application. I am recently migrated from java to .net and any suggestion will be greatly helpful. As a example

I am on **Page1** and while i am idle on **Page1** my session was destroyed and i was redirected to **Logging** page. After i logging to system currently i am on **Default** page. What i want to do is simply redirect to **Page1** after logging. Sorry for my bad English.

Here is Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

and the login button function
    #region"Validate login user"
        public void ValidateUser()
        {

```
        try
        {
            string con = ConnectionSetting.SQLDBConnectionString();
            sUserNameT = this.txtUname.Text.ToLower();
            sPassWordT = this.txtPassword.Text;
            Some required functions user......

            if (check some stuff)
            {
                Decrypting and other stuff....
                if (matching password)
                {
                    if (if the logging success)
                    {
                        LoadScreensByUser(userbyactive.UserId, con);
                        UserLogedDetails(userbyactive.UserId);//Log User Loging Records.
                        Response.Redirect("~/Main.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Output...();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Output...();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Output...();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Here i have provided the minimum required codes..

Comment: If you use Forms authentication in asp.net the default behavior when requesting Page1 with expired authentication ticket would be to go to login page and then be redirected to page1, so maybe some configuration is wrong? Do you use a login form that you've written yourself or do you use the asp.net login control?

Comment: We are using custom login page.

Comment: Please show us the config for forms authentication from web.config and the code in your "login button click" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
Response.Redirect("~/Main.aspx");
```

to this method

[`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userbyactive.UserId, false);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx)

otherwize you will always end up in the page `Main.aspx`

`RedirectFromLoginPage` will send you to the page the borwser previously requested.

Comment: After i added your code i got an error message called `Requested URL: /default.aspx not found on the server `. How ever i want to redirect to ~/Main.aspx page. Any idea ..?

Comment: This method should redirect you to the url that is sent via querystring to login page eg: login.asp?returnUrl=<xxx.aspx>

Comment: I added `defaultUrl="index.aspx"` into `authentication` section and it solved the problem.. Still want to check whether redirect working or not..

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your `web.config` file

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Index.aspx" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
```

for more on Authenticatio modes with asp.net see [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [THIS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaps_deo/Authentication07242007033135AM/Authentication.aspx)

Comment: How can i implement this concept with customized login page.